# reverse order of publications grouped by year

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

For archiving the publications in my Rails app, I group the publications by year:

```
app/controllers/publications_controller.rb
...
def series
  @publications = Publication.all
  @publications_year = @publications.group_by { |p| p.year}
end
```

then in the view, I want to have a link for each publication year:

```
      <% @publications_year.sort.each do |year, pubs| %>
        <li><i class="fa fa-folder left"></i><%= link_to year, archive_path(year) %></a>
      </li>
      <% end %>
```

this works fine, the result is:

```
2012
2013
2014
```

However, I need to reverse the order, so the links should be ordered like this:

```
2014
2013
2012
...
```

But I can't figure out how to this

Does anyone know how I can reverse the order of the year links?

thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also let the db do the ordering.

```
@publications_year = @publications.order('year DESC').group_by { |p| p.year }
```

If you do it this way, you don't need to call `sort` anymore.

Comment: +1 If you intend on adding pagination or any kind of limiting you should be doing the ordering in the controller as per this answer - not in the view.

Comment: thanks a lot jvnill, I implemented your code and it works. This is indeed better, also makes my view code a lot cleaner.

Comment: @papirtiger, yes, I'm planning to implement pagination in a later phase. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

did you try using the `reverse` method?

```
@publications_year.sort.reverse.each
```

source: http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reverse